# ActionController::Live(Rails4), Pub/Sub(Redis) on Heroku doesn't work

Tags: ruby, heroku, redis, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

I'm trying use ActionController::Live, Pub/Sub(Redis) on Heroku, but it doesn't work.
I'm using Ruby2.0.0p247, Rails4, Puma.

I want to make chat like this. RailsCast( http://railscasts.com/episodes/401-actioncontroller-live?view=asciicast ),GitHub( https://github.com/railscasts/401-actioncontroller-live/tree/master/chatter-after )

My code is like this.

beginner_messages_controller.rb

```
class BeginnerMessagesController < ApplicationController

include ActionController::Live

def index
  @beginner_messages = BeginnerMessage.all.order("created_at DESC")

end

def create  
  response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/javascript"
  attributes = params.require(:beginner_message).permit(:body)
  @beginner_message = BeginnerMessage.new(attributes)
  @beginner_message.user = current_user
  @beginner_message.save

  json_message = @beginner_message.to_json
  hash_result = JSON.parse(json_message)
  hash_result[:username] = @beginner_message.user.username
  hash_result[:created_at] = @beginner_message.created_at.strftime("%H:%M")
  @json_result = hash_result.to_json
  $redis.publish('beginner_messages.create', @json_result)
end

def events
  response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"
  redis = Redis.new
  redis.psubscribe('beginner_messages.*') do |on|
  on.pmessage do |pattern, event, data|
       response.stream.write("event: #{event}\n")
       response.stream.write("data: #{data}\n\n")
     end
   end
 end
rescue IOError
  logger.info "Stream closed"
ensure
  redis.quit
  response.stream.close
end
```

beginner_messages.js.coffee

```
source = new EventSource('/beginner_messages/events')
source.addEventListener 'beginner_messages.create', (e) ->
  beginner_message = $.parseJSON(e.data)
  $('#chat').prepend($('<li>').text("#{beginner_message.username} $ #{beginner_message.body} #{beginner_message.created_at}").css("listStyleType","none"))
```

At the localhost, it's working, but not on Heroku. Puma and Redis is working on Heroku.

I did search on the web, but no help. Please tell me what I should do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necro an old thread, but anyone else having this issue could try this in their terminal:

`$ heroku labs:enable websockets`